# Is regular expression search guaranteed to return first match?

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a method to return the first match of a given regexp in a string. It looks like [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) is exactly the method I am looking for.

However, the documentation is not explicit about whether the first match is guaranteed to be returned from search method.

The documentation claims that the method "scans through string" which suggests to me that it does so from the beginning of the string.

However I need some strong argument. Merely testing that `cat1` is found in `cat1cat2` is not enough.

The best would be a hint to official documentation or implementation.

Comment: Yes, it `re.search` will do that for you. Have a look at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/lV5rN4) to try things out.

Comment: I do expect that re.search returns first match. I even stronly believe that. But I would like some better argument than a mere simple empirical test.

Comment: Added: http://bugs.python.org/issue21593

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't want to read through the code for `re.search`, because there's a lot of it. However, if we look at the code for [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.sub), we see that it uses `re.search`, and `re.sub` **is** guaranteed to replace the leftmost occurrence of the pattern. Therefore, `re.search` must return it.

Relevant code from `_sre.c` (comments replace lengthy irrelevant code)

```c
static PyObject*
pattern_subx(PatternObject* self, PyObject* ptemplate, PyObject* string,
             Py_ssize_t count, Py_ssize_t subn)
{
    // init stuff...
    while (!count || n < count) {

        state_reset(&state);

        state.ptr = state.start;

        status = sre_search(&state, PatternObject_GetCode(self));
        // Do the replacement...
```

**Edit:**

Thanks to [@Veedrac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763356/veedrac) opening the [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue21593), the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.search) has been clarified to state

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding match
>   object.

Comment: That's the kind of answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Yes - `re.search` will return the earliest ("starts first") possible match.

(Which might not be the longest/best match that it *could* have matched.)

Comment: Note: I've not been able to find official documentation that explicitly states this behavior, implied meaning of the word "scan" aside, but that's just How It Works.

Comment: Any argument for "that's how it works" other than a strong suspicion? Are you I-am-willing-to-bet-all-my-stackoverflow-reputation-on-it sure?

Comment: Of _course_ it is the best match; it's first! What other criterion could you possibly want?

Comment: @DonalFellows i.e. longest

Comment: @Kuba I would bet all my SO reputation on it - yes. My wellness - no.

Answer (score 3):

Since I am 99.999% sure that first is intended, I changed 'a location' to 'the first location' in the re.search entry of the doc.